# How to access the BufReader twice?

Tags: loops, rust, iterator

Trying to access the variable *sentences* for a second time causes `value used here after move`, I want to understand how to store the total without causing this problem.

I tried to copy the iterator but I can't find a way to make it work or how is the correct way to do it.

```
extern crate regex;

use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let sentences_path = Path::new("csv/testSentences.csv");
    let sentences = BufReader::new(File::open(&sentences_path).unwrap());

    let total = sentences.lines().count();

    for (index, sentence) in sentences.lines().enumerate() {
        let line = sentence.unwrap();
        println!("Processed {} of {}, {}", index, total, line);
    }

    println!("Total {}", total);
}
```

Comment: The two answers this question have, are both trade off, you don't have a lot of memory or your file is really big, read it twice ? Or your file size is small and you have enough memory, stock the whole file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not access the value if the ownership is moved previously. However you can inspect over your lines with [inspect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Inspect.html) without changing the inner lines but only updating the count.

After you find out the `count` by iterating the Lines, you can iterate it again and do the logic as you wish.

The main reason why you are getting this compiler error is: [count](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count) function consumes the Lines you use and you can not access your variable again since it is already consumed.

Here is the solution:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Write};

fn main() {
    let path = "lines.txt";

    let mut output = File::create(path).unwrap();
    write!(output, "Rust\n\nFun").unwrap();

    let input = File::open(path).unwrap();
    let buffered = BufReader::new(input);

    let lines: Vec<_> = buffered.lines().collect();
    let total = lines.len();

    for (index, sentence) in lines.into_iter().enumerate() {
        let line = sentence.unwrap();
        println!("Processed {} of {}, {}", index, total, line);
    }

    println!("Total {}", total);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d420b0b268e1b599e5eccc0e480a068)

*With this way, you do not need to read the file twice. You read the file, put it into memory then only iterate it twice.*

Comment: You need to mention the fact that with this solution all the File is put in memory when you collect lines

Comment: Updated as the file put into memory

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You need to read the file twice. First to count total lines. And second to process each line. So you need two `BufReader`:

```rust
extern crate regex;                                                                                                     

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::path::Path;

fn get_file_reader(path: &Path) -> impl BufRead {
    BufReader::new(File::open(path).unwrap())
}

fn main() {
    let sentences_path = Path::new("csv/testSentences.csv");
    let sentences = get_file_reader(&sentences_path);

    let total = get_file_reader(&sentences_path).lines().count();

    for (index, sentence) in sentences.lines().enumerate() {
        let line = sentence.unwrap();
        println!("Processed {} of {}, {}", index, total, line);
    }

    println!("Total {}", total);
}
```

Comment: With this implementation you are reading the whole file to the memory twice which is not memory efficient

Comment: @Websterix memory efficient mean less memory use, this solution use less memory than your solution where you stock the whole file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the seek or rewind functions to reset the position of the files to start.
See the links:

[seek and rewind](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html)
[rust-by-example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/file/read_lines.html)
[BufRead](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/std/io/trait.BufRead.html)
[why-can-i-not-iterate-over-the-lines-of-a-file-after-counting-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74667471/why-can-i-not-iterate-over-the-lines-of-a-file-after-counting-them)

Note that memmap2::Mmap do not need to rewind the file.

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs;
use std::io::{
    BufRead,
    BufReader,
    Seek,
    //SeekFrom,
};
use std::path::Path;
//use memmap2::Mmap;
//use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    fs::write("test.txt", b"line1\nline2\nline3")?;
    let path = Path::new("test.txt");

    let (file, number_of_lines) = get_file(path)?;

    println!("number_of_lines: {number_of_lines}");

    for (index, line_result) in BufReader::new(&file).lines().enumerate() {
        println!("index {index}: {}", line_result?);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Such that

```
/// File is an object providing access to an open file on the filesystem.
/// Use the seek or rewind functions to reset the position of the files to start.
fn get_file<P>(path: P) -> Result<(fs::File, usize), Box<dyn Error>>
where
    P: AsRef<Path> + std::marker::Copy + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    let mut file = match fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(false)
        .create(false)
        .open(path)
    {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(error) => {
            panic!("Failed to open file {path:?}\n{error}");
        }
    };

    // Count function consumes the Lines
    let number_of_lines = BufReader::new(&file).lines().count();

    /*
    // https://docs.rs/memmap2/latest/memmap2/struct.Mmap.html
    let number_of_lines = unsafe { Mmap::map(&file)? }
        .lines()
        //.par_split(|&byte| byte == b'\n')
        .count();
    */

    if number_of_lines == 0 {
        panic!("The file {path:?} has no lines.");
    }

    // Reset files position to start
    // file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0))?;
    file.rewind()?;

    Ok((file, number_of_lines))
}
```

[Rust Playgrond](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2d98084b0be602bbc8acd58f4ce33469)

The output:

```
number_of_lines: 3
index 0: line1
index 1: line2
index 2: line3
```

Answer (score -1):

`sentences.lines()` is an iterator. You can borrow it instead of consuming by calling `.by_ref()`:

```rust
let mut lines = sentences.lines();
let total = lines.by_ref().count();
for (index, sentence) in lines.enumerate() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This simply doesn't work, `by_ref()` will not clone the iterator, it will just do a mutate borrow.