# Why can I not iterate over the lines of a file after counting them?

Tags: file, rust, iterator

I am attempting to write a program that shortens a file to n lines.

I have difficulties with counting the lines of the file and then enumerating over them after. Using a single iterator does not work since `.count()` is called on it which consumes the iterator. However, creating two separate buffers from the file produces similar results?

```rust
let file_path = Path::new(&args[1]);
let file_result = OpenOptions::new().read(true).open(file_path);
let file = match file_result {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(error) => {
        panic!("failed to open file: {}", error.to_string());
    }
};

let lines_amount = BufReader::new(&file).lines().count();
if lines_amount == 0 {
    panic!("The file has no lines");
}

println!("{}", lines_amount);

// this will not iterate, no matter the amount of lines in the file
for (i, line_result) in BufReader::new(&file).lines().enumerate() {
    // ...
}
```

Opening two files and create a buffer from each seems to produce the same results.

Why does this happen? How do I read the number of lines of a file and then iterate over them?

Comment: "Opening two files and create a buffer from each seems to produce the same results" - No, it doesn't. Opening the file separately for counting lines and iterating works, see [Rust playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=db4b0887c0ebfe20b964a3af30f404be).

Comment: @kotatsuyaki I must have made a mistake when I tested it then. That was honestly where most of my confusion came from. It makes more sense how it works now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `seek` to the beginning in between uses of a `File` or you'll continue reading where the last `read` left off.
It is a little hidden here because the `Read` on `&File` uses interior mutability and is equivalent to the one on `File`.

```rust
let file_path = Path::new(&args[1]);
let file_result = OpenOptions::new().read(true).open(file_path);
let mut file = match file_result {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(error) => {
        panic!("failed to open file: {}", error.to_string());
    }
};

let lines_amount = BufReader::new(&file).lines().count();
if lines_amount == 0 {
    panic!("The file has no lines");
}

println!("{}", lines_amount);

// reset files position to start
file.seek( std::io::SeekFrom::Start(0));

for (i, line_result) in BufReader::new(&file).lines().enumerate() {
    // ...
}
```